# How to create a session in axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-requests, axios, cheerio

I am trying to log in to a website using forms `data` payload. It requires a `_csrf` token which is uniquely generated every time the `login` page opens up. I was trying to get to the login page to take the `_csrf` id then post the payload in the very same session.

My python code was able to do it with `requests.session()` but I am having trouble with axios.

***My python code***

```
login = {'_csrf': 0, 'email': 'mail@example.com', 'password': "password"}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://example.com/login.html"
    res = s.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soupy = soup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    _csrf = soupy.find('meta', attrs={'name': "csrf-token"})['content']
    login['_csrf'] = _csrf
    res = s.post(url, data=login, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
```

***My Node.js Code***

```
var url = "https://example.com/login.html";
let response = await axios.get(url,{
    headers:{
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    }
})
.then(function(response){
    let soup = cheerio.load(response.data, null, false);
    var _csrf = soup('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var login = {'_csrf': _csrf, 'email': 'mail@example.com', 'password': "password"};
    response = axios.post(url,{
        headers:{
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
        },
        data: login,
    }).catch((e)=> {console.log(e)});
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

but it doesn't work as I get a `_csrf` mismatch error. What can I do to get `axios` work in a session?

Comment: You're probably not setting the CSRF token inside the 'Cookie' header as well which is what it'll be matching to, causing the "mismatch". Using the developer tools check for a CSRF token inside the network request headers, on most websites, it's simply the 'Cookie: CSRF=token;' to do automatic session management maybe look into using https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support

Comment: @conor reid It is uniquely generated each time page loads up. Thats why i need to be in the same session while i post my data. How cokkies can help is beyond me

Comment: You need to set content type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded ???) and the payload in the right format (foo=bar ???)